# Create ul li with jquery and put it in the html append

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I got input and textarea, so problem is that I'mm sending ajax with some text and words and counting how much inputs have word in a text, and sending back list of objects of class which have 2 vals:quantity and word,and then i want to show a result like that:"word"-quantity" and these all things i need to put in ul li,so i tried to created ul and li with jquery but still cant get how to put it  in my html append now with vals of list.
Thats my part of code:

```
function makeulli() {
    var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(data, function (i) {
        var sub_li = $('<li/>');
        $(sub_li).appendTo(sub_ul);
    });
}

$(".texnwords").append("<section class='searchresult'><h4>Result:</h4><p>Words: <p>Text:<br>" + text + "</p></section>");
```

So i just need to put this created ul and li's in my append with values from list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to access the data variable you can do like this:

```
function makeulli() {
   var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       // access like value.yourvalue
       var sub_li = $('<li/>');
       sub_ul.append(sub_li);
   });   
   $(".texnwords").append(sub_ul);         
}
```

Update:

Guess you mean like this?

```
function makeulli() {
   var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       var sub_li = $('<li/>').html(value.word+'-'+value.quantity);
       sub_ul.append(sub_li);
   });   
   $(".texnwords").append(sub_ul);         
}
```

If in doubt, how the data structure for the variable is, then try console.log() either the "value" or "data".

Comment: ye did just like you said and its showing up like [object Object]

Comment: Try console.log(value) inside the loop, to see how your object is structured.

Comment: Array[1]
0:Object
q:2
w:"sad" thats structure of data

Comment: thats result of console.log value Object
q:2
w:"sad"

Comment: Yeah okay, then just use value.q, and value.w to get your values. You can also try value[index].q, if it's a multidimension array you're in.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you create the array or object, then I can give an exact answer.

Comment: hm i just did like that value[index].q and for w and there is error now like:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of undefined

Comment: Array[3]
0:Object
q:2
w:"wex"
__proto__:
Object
1:
Object
q:2
w:"weq"
__proto__:
Object2
:
Object
q:2
w:"wer"

Comment: I ment where you created it, but I've tried to do a fiddle for you, it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/htxckmhw/2/

Comment: public class wordsinf
    {
        public string w;
        public int q;
        public wordsinf(string wf,int quan)
        {
            w = wf;
            q = quan;
        }
    }

Comment: List<wordsinf> result = new List<wordsinf>();